# How print a array struct in another function in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

i wanna make a fuction to print all date in struct array after the user press certain key(1 in that case) and stop the loop, and if he press 2 the loop continue until the array get full or the user press 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h >
struct dat {
    int age;
    char name[50];
    int score;
    int trab[2];
};

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    struct dat people[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        gets(people[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &people[i]age);
        scanf("%d", &people[i].score );
        scanf("%d", &people[i].trab[0]);
        scanf("%d", &people[i].trab[1]);
        scanf("%d", x);
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                continue;
        }
    }
    imp(people[i]);
    return 0;
}

int imp(struct dat people[i])
{   
    int i;

    printf("%s", people[0].name);
    printf("%d", &people[0].age);
    printf("%d", &people[0].score );
    printf("%d", &people[0].trab[0]);
    printf("%d", &people[0].trab[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `switchcase` are using `break`, I think using this will not give you the expected result. Maybe you could simply try using an `if else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your code cannot compile in this state.

Your compiler should tell you why some line do not compile, first try to correct errors.

Once errors are corrected, turn on compiler warning, and handle them.

---

The line

```
#include <string.h >
```

Will raise this error: `fatal error: string.h : No such file or directory`

Why a space between `h` and `>` ?

---

The function `gets` should not be used: from [man gets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)

> Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead.

So 
    gets(people[i].name);

should be

```
fgets(stdin, people[i].name, sizeof people[i].name);
```

---

The following line is missing a dot `.`

```
scanf("%d", &people[i]age);
```

---

Since `x` is 0, this next line dereference the `NULL` pointer (which you don't want):

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

You should write:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

---

Then you call `imp` function on `people[i]`, but `imp` is not declared, and i is not defined (it's a variable local to `for` loop)

```
imp(people[i]);
```

---

The `imp` definition is not valid:

```
int imp(struct dat people[i])
```

Should be something like:

```
/* function to display ONE person */
int imp(struct dat people)
```

or

```
/* function to display ALL peopel */
int imp(struct dat *people, int number_of_people)
```

Comment: Also, `imp` is missing forward declaration.